# Как использовать медиазапросы в Link для стилей

Tags: css, веб-программирование, style, теги

Есть список разрешений и стилей для них:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1299px)and (max-width: 1399px)and (min-height:690px) and (max-height:710px)" type="text/css" href="css/style13602.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" media=" screen and (min-width:300px)and (max-width: 399px) and (min-height:599px) and (max-height:699px)" type="text/css" href="css/mobile320.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:300px)and (max-width: 399px) and (min-height:599px) and (max-height:699px)" type="text/css" href="css/stylesmall200.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:100px) and (max-width: 599px) and (min-height:100px) and (max-height:699px)" type="text/css" href="css/stylesmall100.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:500px) and (max-width: 799px) and (min-height:900px) and (max-height:1099px)"  type="text/css" href="css/stylesmall500.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1000px)and (max-width: 1299px)and (min-height:601px) and (max-height:1099px)" type="text/css" href="css/stylesmall1000.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:599px) and (max-width: 699px) and (min-height:999px) and (max-height:1099px)" type="text/css" href="css/stylesmall.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:999px) and (max-width: 1099px)and (min-height:599px)and (max-height:799px)" type="text/css" href="css/stylesmall.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1800px)and (max-width: 2000px)and (min-height:800px) and (max-height:1100px)" type="text/css" href="css/style1100.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1299px)and (max-width: 1399px)and (min-height:720px) and (max-height:799px)" type="text/css" href="css/style1360.css"> 

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1299px)and (max-width: 1599px)and (min-height:799px) and (max-height:899px)" type="text/css" href="css/style1360.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1599px)and (max-width: 1899px)and (min-height:499px) and (max-height:899px)" type="text/css" href="css/style1360.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1599px)and (max-width: 1799px)and (min-height:545px) and (max-height:899px)" type="text/css" href="css/stylesmall.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1800px)and (max-width: 2000px)and (min-height:800px) and (max-height:1099px)" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:599px)and (max-width: 800px)and (min-height:545px) and (max-height:899px)" type="text/css" href="css/stylesmall.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:799px)and (max-width: 999px)and (min-height:545px) and (max-height:899px)" type="text/css" href="css/stylesmall.css">
```

Как мне назначить стиль, который будет применяться при несовпадении в медиа-запросах? То есть, чтобы на какое-нибудь совсем нестандартное разрешение какой-то стиль обязательно применился, заданный мной? нашёл media="all", но он тогда не обращает внимания на другие медиа. Помогите!

Comment: на сколько я знаю, именно в этом месте нельзя написать конкретно разрешение экрана, но можно указать тип, например: `all`, `screen`, `print` и т. д. Но указать разрешение вы можете внутри самого файла `css` например обернув все содержимое файла в медиазапрос `@media (max-width: 600px) {  /*TODO*/ }` и файлик со стилями применится для всех до `600 px`

Comment: Вопрос в том, что для каждого разрешения мне нужен свой Css. Делать один Css с @media внутри - слишком огромный получится. А media="all" перекрывает другие разрешения. Если проще - задать link media для 1920*1080 отдельно, 1360*700 отдельно, а для других применять общий стиль -это мне нужно.

Comment: в медиа есть оператор `not` - он вам поможет

Comment: В таком случае мне придётся использовать в два раза больше link верно? или я могу перечислить через not противоположные условия в одной записи link?

Comment: Это нужно делать внутри файла `css`